# Find NAs and visualize it

Tags: r

I have data as:

```
MyData.csv <- "
0, 980, 888, 720,987,543
0, 880, 999, 820,990, NA, NA, 898, 780,987
1, 945, 856, 767,745,883
2, 780, 899, 920, NA, NA, NA, 998, 870,787
2, 800, 900, 822,999,880, 988, 899"
```

i want to find one row with NA to visualize.
i tried to read the data using read.table()

```
data <-read.table("MyData.csv", sep = ",", strip.white = TRUE)
which(data[, 2:ncol(data)]== is.na(data[, 2:ncol(data)]))
```

but i had error from first line of code since i have different length of rows, and im not sure im using a correct approach to find at least one row (i don't want to read the entire data) with NAs so i can plot it.

Comment: do you know the maximum number of columns in your data?

Comment: around 26543 columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the number of columns in your file, then you can try replacing your first line by

```
data <- read.table("MyData.csv", header = FALSE, sep = ",",
           col.names = paste0("V",seq_len(n.cols)), fill = TRUE)
```

with `n.cols` the number of columns in the file.

Then you can find the indices of the rows that have at least one NA with

```
na.rows <- which(apply(data, 1, function(x) any(is.na(x))))
```

Finally you can access any row with NAs you want like this

```
data[na.rows[1],]
data[na.rows[2],]
...
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You're working with comma-separated data, so `read.csv` instead of `read.table`.
2. Normally the first argument is a filename, so it is looking for a file named `"MyData.csv"`. This looks normal (since you named your variable that way), but here I think you should be looking at the object named `MyData.csv` instead. For here, I think `text=MyData.csv`.
3. Your sample data here has no `header=`, and `read.csv` defaults to having a header, so `header=FALSE`.

Ultimately,

```r
x <- read.csv(text=MyData.csv, header=FALSE)
x
#   V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  V6   V7  V8  V9 V10
# 1  0 980 888 720 987 543       NA  NA  NA
# 2  0 880 999 820 990  NA   NA 898 780 987
# 3  1 945 856 767 745 883       NA  NA  NA
# 4  2 780 899 920  NA  NA   NA 998 870 787
# 5  2 800 900 822 999 880  988 899  NA  NA
```

To get those with at least one `NA`:

```r
x[!complete.cases(x),]
#   V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  V6   V7  V8 V9 V10
# 1  0 980 888 720 987 543       NA NA  NA
# 3  1 945 856 767 745 883       NA NA  NA
# 5  2 800 900 822 999 880  988 899 NA  NA
```

If you need just one of the, you can either always use the first (append `[1,]` to that line of code) or sample from them.

```r
xsamp <- x[!complete.cases(x),]
set.seed(42)
xsamp[sample(nrow(xsamp), size=1),]
#   V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  V6   V7  V8 V9 V10
# 5  2 800 900 822 999 880  988 899 NA  NA
xsamp[sample(nrow(xsamp), size=1),]
#   V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  V6   V7  V8 V9 V10
# 5  2 800 900 822 999 880  988 899 NA  NA
xsamp[sample(nrow(xsamp), size=1),]
#   V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
# 1  0 980 888 720 987 543    NA NA  NA
```